# how to combine queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

Good day.

[**Structure tables in SqlFidle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd60dc)

I have some queries:

**Query 1.**

```
SELECT 
    n.Type as Type,
    n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    u.Username as Username,
    n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
    n.Header as Header,
    n.Text as Text,
    n.Tags as Tags,
    n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
    n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
    n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
FROM News n
```

**Query 2.**

```
Select count(*) as Uplikes FROM Likes WHERE Type = 'up' AND NewsIdn='730456' 
// value NewsIdn for example
```

**Query 3.**

```
Select count(*) as DownLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type = 'down' AND NewsIdn='730456' 
// value NewsIdn for example
```

I would combine queries that get `Uplikes` and `DownLikes` from each row table `News` in **query 1** (each row table `News` have unique value NewsIdn).

Tell me please how make it?

P.S.: in result i would be get next - http://clip2net.com/clip/m264191/1389339754-clip-63kb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    n.Type AS TYPE,
    n.UserIdn AS UserIdn,
    u.Username AS Username,
    n.NewsIdn AS NewsIdn,
    n.Header AS Header,
    n.Text AS TEXT,
    n.Tags AS Tags,
    n.ImageLink AS ImageLink,
    n.VideoLink AS VideoLink,
    n.DateCreate AS DateCreate, 
    SUM(l.Type = 'up') Uplikes, 
    SUM(l.Type = 'down') Downlikes
FROM News n 
INNER JOIN Users u ON n.UserIdn = u.UserIdn 
LEFT JOIN Likes l ON n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn
GROUP BY n.id
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd60dc/7)

```
|  TYPE | USERIDN | USERNAME | NEWSIDN | HEADER |                      TEXT |      TAGS |      IMAGELINK | VIDEOLINK |                      DATECREATE | UPLIKES | DOWNLIKES |
|-------|---------|----------|---------|--------|---------------------------|-----------|----------------|-----------|---------------------------------|---------|-----------|
| image |  346412 |     test |  260806 |   test |                           |           | 1388152519.jpg |           | December, 27 2013 08:55:27+0000 |       2 |         0 |
| image |  108546 |    test2 |  905554 |  test2 | 1231231111111111111111111 |  123, 123 | 1388153493.jpg |           | December, 27 2013 09:11:41+0000 |       1 |         0 |
|  text |  108546 |    test2 |  270085 |  test3 |                           | 123 ,123  |                |           | December, 27 2013 09:13:30+0000 |       1 |         0 |
| image |  108546 |    test2 |  764955 |  test4 |                           |           | 1388192300.jpg |           | December, 27 2013 19:58:22+0000 |       0 |         1 |
```

Comment: tell me please why `INNER JOIN Users`? why not `LEFT JOIN Users` ?